# Правильно ли расставлены знаки перепинания?

Tags: пунктуация

Резюмирую: наша компания держится на трех китах — надежность нашего оборудования, надежность нас как поставщика и инженерная компетенция.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разберемся. Согласно правилам, если однородные члены предложения носят характер приложения или уточнения, то после обобщающего слова вместо двоеточия ставится ***тире***. В вашем случае однородные члены предложения имеют уточняющий характер.Ср.напр.:  Алый цвет заливал окрестности - ветряную мельницу, шиферные крыши машинно тракторной станции, элеваторы(Кат.). Двоеточие тоже поставлено верно. После двоеточия можно поставить "а именно". См. Обобщающие слова при однородных членах предложения. стр.153.Справочник-практикум. Д.Э. Розенталь.